# Question on UDP : Packet containing multiple mesages and straddling

Tags: sockets, udp, datagram

In the context of a UDP Message that I receive the UDP Message will have apart from the header containing the size of the overall packet, the second field is an unsigned int indicating a sequence number. The rest of packet is PayLoad [ actual message(s) ].

The payload contains zero or more messages which need to be further decoded and parsed. Now there is the below requirement in design.

"Messages can straddle packet boundaries."

What does this sentence mean in layman terms?

Comment: Are you asking about the UDP protocol itself, or about some specific application-level protocol that is being transported across the network using UDP packets?

Comment: My question is not specific to UDP itself but what does message straddling mean here? by the first answer I can see below it means I can receive partial messages in a packet and the rest of it may arrive in a later sequence of UDP packet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be quite simple. A *message* is thought not to be the same as a *packet*, and the former may be scattered across multiple packets.
Say, the first part of the message may reside in the first packet whilst the rest of it in the second.

Comment: so a packet may have 3 partial messages none of which are complete and some sequence of packets down the road i might recieve rest of the message pieces in any order ?

Comment: Please note that in requirement it is mentioned that the payload in packet is zero or more messages [ which means to say 0 or 1 or more messages which may be partial or complete as well ].